# In Rust, what's the difference between "shadowing" and "mutability"?

Tags: variables, rust, immutability, mutability, shadowing

In [Chapter 3 of the Rust Book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/2018-edition/ch03-01-variables-and-mutability.html), *Variables and Mutability*, we go through a couple iterations on this theme in order to demonstrate the default, immutable behavior of variables in Rust:

```
fn main() {
    let x = 5;
    println!("The value of x is {}", x);
    x = 6;
    println!("The value of x is {}", x);
}
```

Which outputs:

```
error[E0384]: cannot assign twice to immutable variable `x`
 --> src/main.rs:4:5
  |
2 |     let x = 5;
  |         -
  |         |
  |         first assignment to `x`
  |         help: make this binding mutable: `mut x`
3 |     println!("The value of x is {}", x);
4 |     x = 6;
  |     ^^^^^ cannot assign twice to immutable variable
```

However, because of Rust's take on *shadowing* variables, we can simply do this to change the value of the nonetheless "immutable" `x`:

```
fn main() {
    let x = 5;
    println!("The value of x is {}", x);
    let x = 6;
    println!("The value of x is {}", x);
}
```

Which outputs (skipping the details):

```
The value of x is 5
The value of x is 6
```

Funnily enough, this code also produces the above pair of lines as output, despite the fact that we don't call `let` but instead `mut` the first time `x` is bound to `5`:

```
fn main() {
    let mut x = 5;
    println!("The value of x is {}", x);
    x = 6;
    println!("The value of x is {}", x);
}
```

This ambiguity in how variables are (not really) protected from reassignment seems contrary to the stated goal of protecting the values bound to immutable - by Rust default - variables. From the same chapter (which also contains the section *Shadowing*):

> It’s important that we get compile-time errors when we attempt to
>   change a value that we previously designated as immutable because this
>   very situation can lead to bugs. If one part of our code operates on
>   the assumption that a value will never change and another part of our
>   code changes that value, it’s possible that the first part of the code
>   won’t do what it was designed to do. The cause of this kind of bug can
>   be difficult to track down after the fact, especially when the second
>   piece of code changes the value only sometimes.
>
> In Rust, the compiler guarantees that when you state that a value
>   won’t change, it really won’t change. That means that when you’re
>   reading and writing code, you don’t have to keep track of how and
>   where a value might change. Your code is thus easier to reason
>   through.

If I can cause this important feature of my immutable `x` to be side-stepped with an innocent enough call to `let`, why do I need `mut`? Is there some way to really, seriously-you-guys make `x` immutable, such that no `let x` can reassign its value?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

I believe the confusion is because you're conflating names with storage.

```
fn main() {
    let x = 5; // x_0
    println!("The value of x is {}", x);
    let x = 6; // x_1
    println!("The value of x is {}", x);
}
```

In this example, there is one name (`x`), and two storage locations (`x_0` and `x_1`).  The second `let` is simply re-binding the name `x` to refer to storage location `x_1`.  The `x_0` storage location is entirely unaffected.

```
fn main() {
    let mut x = 5; // x_0
    println!("The value of x is {}", x);
    x = 6;
    println!("The value of x is {}", x);
}
```

In this example, there is one name (`x`), and one storage location (`x_0`).  The `x = 6` assignment is directly changing the bits of storage location `x_0`.

You might argue that these do the same thing.  If so, you would be wrong:

```
fn main() {
    let x = 5; // x_0
    let y = &x; // y_0
    println!("The value of y is {}", y);
    let x = 6; // x_1
    println!("The value of y is {}", y);
}
```

This outputs:

```
The value of y is 5
The value of y is 5
```

This is because changing which storage location `x` refers to has absolutely no effect on the storage location `x_0`, which is what `y_0` contains a pointer to.  However,

```
fn main() {
    let mut x = 5; // x_0
    let y = &x; // y_0
    println!("The value of y is {}", y);
    x = 6;
    println!("The value of y is {}", y);
}
```

This fails to compile because you cannot mutate `x_0` while it is borrowed.

Rust cares about protecting against unwanted mutation effects *as observed through references*.  This doesn't conflict with allowing shadowing, because you're not changing values when you shadow, you're just changing what a particular name means in a way that cannot be observed anywhere else.  Shadowing is a strictly local change.

So yes, you absolutely can keep the value of `x` from being changed.  What you *can't* do is keep what the name `x` refers to from being changed.  At most, you can use something like [`clippy`](https://crates.io/crates/clippy) to deny shadowing as a lint.

Comment: Excellent answer, especially the part about failure due to being borrowed.  I'll wait a few days then accept.  Is there a way to print all the values chained to the same variable (ie in this example if I wanted to see all x_i for x, in this case x_0 and x_1)?

Comment: @d8aninja nope.

Comment: Nobody's shocked by the expression "immutable variable" ? Aren't they antonyms ?